# How can I use CKEditor for teaser text on a long form text field?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

In Drupal 8, the teaser text for a long form text field (specifically, text of type "long, formatted, with summary") does not have a CKEditor wrapper around it:

[image]

How can CKEditor be added to this textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is core limitation right now.

I would recommend that if you want an editor on a teaser/summary field, you simply create a separate field, that also gives you options like having a separate text format for it.

The text long with summary field type might eventually get removed in Drupal 9 or so.